# Giving a new id based on several attributes

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|att1 | att2| att3|  id |
+-----------------------+
| a   |  b  |  a  |  1  |
| b   |  c  |  c  |  2  |
| a   |  b  |  a  |  3  |
+-----------------------+
```

with a few columns and an ID. I would like to replace that ID with a new ID which is equal if att1, att2 and att3 are equal , like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|att1 | att2| att3|  id |
+-----------------------+
| a   |  b  |  a  |  1  |
| b   |  c  |  c  |  2  |
| a   |  b  |  a  |  1  |
+-----------------------+
```

I tried the classical merge into statement with a dense_rank() function over the attributes, like this:

```
merge into the_table t
using (
  select att1, att2, att3, dense_rank() over (partition by att1, att2, att3 order by att1) as rnk
  from the_table 
) x on (x.att1 = t.att1 and x.att2 = t.att2 and t.att3 = x.att3)
when matched then update
   set old_id = x.new_id;
```

But that does not work, because `select att1, att2, att3, dense_rank() over (partition by att1, att2, att3 order by att1) as rnk` does not give every partition of att1, att2 and att3 its own rank as I expected, but rather everything just gets the rank 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this is a wrong approach. How would you distinguish the identical rows? Instead of updating the id column, which creates duplicate rows, try updating the existing child records to the other id and remove the duplicate id record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

The select with the rank function should look like this, then it works as expected

```
select att1, att2, att3, dense_rank() over (order by att1, att2, att3) as rnk
```

So putting the attributes that should get the same rank into the order by instead of the partition by

Comment: . . This is the better solution.  I would recommend accepting your own answer.

Comment: I must wait 2 days to accept my own solution so I will accept it if I do not forget

Answer (score 3):

This is just another option-

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bdb2dd7a38ef255b114c1f0591eae4c7)

```
SELECT A.att1,A.att2,A.att3, B.RN id
FROM your_table A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT att1,att2,att3,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY att1,att2,att3) RN
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY att1,att2,att3
)B ON A.att1 = B.att1 AND A.att2 = B.att2 AND A.att3 = B.att3
ORDER BY A.Id
```